# Virtuoso high load when using dbpedia

Tags: dbpedia, virtuoso

I've set up a local `Dbpedia` mirror - individual queries work just fine but I'm getting the following errors from `Virtuoso` when I try a higher amount of queries:

```
17:45:46 WARNING: * Monitor: System is under high load. Adding cluster nodes or using more replicated copies may needed
17:47:03 WARNING: * Monitor: Locks are held for a long time
17:47:40 WARNING: * Monitor: No Web Server threads avalable, ServerThreads in [HTTP Server] may have to be increased
```

Any ideas of how to fix this?  I've increased the `ServerThreads` already in `virtuoso.ini`.

Comment: Virtuoso-specific questions are often better raised to the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp)... (ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Comment: Virtuoso documentation includes a number of [Performance Tuning settings](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFPerformanceTuning) that may be relevant...